# Why am I getting invalid left hand assignment when using Blaze with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying out Meteor 0.8 version. I created client and server folders and in client folder I have controller.js where I removed the isClient if check. Now I have only

```
Template.view.modelitem = function() {
    return model.find({}, {sort: {ID: 1}});
};
```

I keep getting "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error pointing to 'Template.view.modelitem' definition. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you post more context, or a more complete, but minimal reproduction, I cannot reproduce this as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's a syntax issue in a preceding line code?

Comment: There are no other line in that code other than these 3 lines.

Comment: Yes there was a syntax error. the name of the function has '-' instead of '_'.